# Wordpress site returns status 500 but still works

Tags: wordpress, http, http-status-code-500

http://ststephens.edu/

This site returns status code 500 (Internal Server Error) when I do 
`wget http://ststephens.edu/` but works fine on my browser. Also as seen in this screenshot, clearly the homepage is a 500 status but the site seems functional.

[image]
What could make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers are more flexible then wget. Even if it receives an error code, it will still display the page content returned along with the error code response. Web servers only fall back on their default error view if no content is provided.

Wget and search engine crawlers are more strict. They will bail out as soon as they see the error code response.

I think there is a problem with your server configuration. Check your web server log file. It may tell you why the server gave this error.

Comment: I would have but this is not my server.